# Vertical and Horizontal Scroll for React Native with support for both IOS and Android

Tags: react-native

I know there are a lot of issues opened with this question but I couldn't find any solution that work for both IOS and Android. The idea is to have `ScrollView` That can be scrolled to both directions (vertical and horizontal). At the moment my code looks like that:

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{height: 1000}}>
    <ScrollView horizontal contentContainerStyle={{width: 1000}}>
     // content
    </ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

It works fine for IOS but no luck with Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ScrollView inside another scrollView you have to use [nestedscroll](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#nestedscrollenabled) prop in scrollview to deal with the scrolling.

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{height: 1000}}>
    <ScrollView horizontal contentContainerStyle={{width: 1000}} nestedScrollEnabled={true}>
     // content
    </ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Use the above code and it will work as expected....

I hope this helps...Thanks :)